# Unified Variable Classification

Tags: continuous-data, discrete-data

I am trying to go beyond Stevens' [Level of Measurement Typology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement). Here is what I have so far:

[image]

## Discrete Variables

- [Nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Nominal_scale) (like Apple, Banana)
- [Ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ordinal_scale) (like 1, 2, 3)
- [Count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_data) (like 0, 1, 2)
- [Incremental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) (like 2015/06/28, 2015/06/29)
- [Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Interval_scale) (like \$10, \$20, \$30)
- [Quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) (like 1st percentile, 2nd percentile)
- [Periodical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics) (like 00:00, 00:01, up to 23:59)

## Continuous Variables

- [Intensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties#Intensive_properties) (like 15°C, 15.1°C, 15.3°C)
- [Extensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties#Extensive_properties) (like 3.14 km, 2 km, 42 km)
- [Absolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) (like 0%, 50%, 100%)
- [Circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics) (like π, 2π)

**Periodical** and **Circular** are names I picked for the discrete and continuous scales that could be created from [Directional Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics), also known as Circular Statistics. [Nicholas R. Chrisman](http://www1.rmit.edu.au/staff/nicholas-chrisman) called the continuous scale **Cyclical Ratio**. This [presentation](http://www4.uwsp.edu/geo/faculty/gmartin/geog476/Lecture/BeySt.htm) provides a very good introduction to his work, even though [Rethinking Levels of Measurement for Cartography](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1559/152304098782383043?journalCode=tcag19) is the reference in the field, but it is not freely available.

I am now trying to integrate three more levels introduced by Stevens and Chrisman:

- Derived Ratio
- Log-Interval
- Graded Membership

For **Graded Membership**, one idea might consist in breaking free of the **Discrete | Continuous** duality and adding an intermediary **Fractal** family. This would dramatically increase the complexity of the underlying framework, but it should open the door to some fascinating developments.

My question is simple: where should **Log-Interval** and **Derived Ratio** fit in the classification, knowing that every continuous scale should have a discrete counterpart? Also, if a **Fractal** family were to be introduced, what would be its scales for every level of the classification (the columns), including **Graded Membership** or its derivatives.

All this is a work in progress captured on the [Sutoiku](http://sutoiku.com/tagged/grammar) blog.